# Converting to phpmailer6 due to server upgrade to php7, namespace error

Tags: namespaces, phpmailer, php-7

I hope someone can help me with converting PHPmailer code.

I have got a bit lost and can't work out where I am going wrong but it seems to be the namespace and use part, I have the following at the moment and although the require pages are OK (tested without the namespace and use code) I can't make it work!

```
namespace MyProject;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/php_mailer/phpmailer.php';
require '/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/php_mailer/SMTP.php';
require '/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/php_mailer/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

FULL Page code

```
    <?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('_JEXEC', 1);   

// this file is in a subfolder 'scripts' under the main joomla folder
define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

// instantiate application
$app   = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// database connection
$dbj     = JFactory::getDbo();

// External database connection
JLoader::discover('Lanoil', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/lanoil');
$config = new LanoilConfig();
$db = new LanoilDb();

if (isset($_POST['deadline'])) {

$deadline = ($_POST['deadline']/1000);

$db->query("update automate set deadline =".$deadline); // adding deadline to db for cron job.

$sql= "SELECT DISTINCT `email` FROM `tbl_clients` where `email` IS NOT NULL";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$emails = array();
foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){
    array_push($emails, $row['email']);     
}

$test = implode(", ",$emails); 
echo $test; 

foreach($emails as $email){
   $mail->AddBCC($email);
}

function url_get_contents ($Url) {
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){ 
        die('CURL is not installed!');
    }
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}


namespace MyProject;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/php_mailer/phpmailer.php';
require '/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/php_mailer/SMTP.php';
require '/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/php_mailer/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);


try {

//$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
  //Create a new PHPMailer instance
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
  $mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
  $mail->Username   = "gordon@rural.co.uk";  // GMAIL username
  $mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password
  $mail->AddReplyTo('gordon@rural.co.uk', 'Gordon Muir');
  $mail->AddAddress('gordon@rural.co.uk', 'Gordon Muir');
  $mail->SetFrom('gordon@rural.co.uk', 'Gordon Muir');
  $mail->AddReplyTo('gordon@rural.co.uk', 'Gordon Muir');
  $mail->Subject = 'Time to order your oil from the Rural Oil Club';
  $mail->AltBody = 'This email is to alert you that it is now time to order your oil from the Rural Oil, Club'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
  $body = url_get_contents(page to call);
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);
  $mail->Send();
  echo "Message Sent OK
<p></p>
  \n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Publish Order Oil menu item
$query = $dbj->getQuery(true);
// Fields to update.
$fields = array(
    $dbj->quoteName('published') . ' = 1'
);
// Conditions for which records should be updated.
$conditions = array(
    $dbj->quoteName('id') . ' = 195'
);
$query->update($dbj->quoteName('#__menu'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);
$dbj->setQuery($query);
$result = $dbj->execute();
}
else
{
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "@" });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
Deadline: <input type="text" name="deadline" id="datepicker"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I haven't changed any of the PHPmailer code for the actual sending of the message yet as I need to get the first part right first. (The code won't be very tidy as I'm not a pro...obviously!)

Comment: That all looks ok - Please post the actual error you're getting. Ah - are you sure `phpmailer.php` is right? Original is `PHPMailer.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy error: `namespace` needs to be the first thing in your file, before any other scripting, and it helps to stick `use` lines at the top too. That will be the error you're getting. This is covered in [the PHP namespace docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php).

Comment: I now get the following error: Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Class 'MyProject\JFactory' not found

Comment: Well that's that you've declared a `MyProject` namespace, but the `JFactory` class can't be found in that namespace. Its entirely possible you don't need the `namespace` directive at all - try deleting it. You'll still need the `use` directives for PHPMailer though.

Comment: When I delete the namespace I get these errors which look like they are related to something else entirely!  Warning: require_once(/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/lanoil/public_html/templates/rt_iridescent/error.php on line 141

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/lanoil/public_html/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/lanoil/public_html/templates/rt_iridescent/error.php on line 141

Comment: I'll through the other PHPMailer settings as they may need changed (After Dinner though!)

Comment: You just need to check where you have put your files.

Comment: I just appear to have a Gmail issue, shortened error:  2017-10-23 20:31:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220-mercury.safeukdns.net ESMTP Exim 4.89 #1 Mon, 23 Oct 2017 21:31:23 +0100 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
2017-10-23 20:31:23 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO lanarkshireoilclub.com
2017-10-23 20:31:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mercury.safeukdns.net 52428800250-8BITMIME250-PIPELINING250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-STARTTLS250 HELP
2017-10-23 20:31:23 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 TLS go ahead
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: You have a TLS problem now - read the guide for more on that.